# Making a particular kind of search engine with Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, customization, plugin-recommendation, repository, search-engines

I would appreciate if I get to know details and how-to make a particular type of search engine with Wordpress,where users can submit/showcase their product and submit their listings of products.It would be a user submitting site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for business directory plugins in the WordPress repository.